# Problem sending MIDI message using Proteus Simulation Software

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, protocol, binary, midi

Im trying to send a MIDI message using Proteus Simulation Software. The idea is to send a NOTE ON, channel 1, C4 music note with velocity of 127. This three bytes are the following.

**(Note ON/channel 1 -->)** 10010000 **(C4 Music Note -->)**  00111100 **(127 velocity -->)**   01111111.

I’m using the 74ls194 for bit shifting with a clock frequency of 31.25kHz.I am using a virtual serial port to link the COMPIM output to a physical baud rate of 38400 via COM1 to send the information to COM2. By means of HAIRLESS MIDI program link this port with LOOPMIDI. Between each byte im using a 0 bit for start and a 1 for stop to have the following information.

**0** 10010000 **1    0** 00111100 **1 0**   01111111 **1**

At the beginning and end of the message I am adding 5 bits of ones in order to separate the message. In this way by rearranging the information and investing the bytes I have the following message.

11111 **0** 00001001 **1    0** 00111100 **1 0**   11111110 **1** 11111

Running the program. The information recorded in HairlessMIDI does not match the message that should be sent. I do not know how the information is interpreted.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The idea is to send a NOTE ON, channel 1, C4 music note with velocity of 127. This information not match with the Debug MIDI messages present in HairlessMIDI.

Comment: You don't ask a question, please add one and info what you have debugged so far. So, have you debugged if Proteus sends the bytes correctly to another terminal? Have you debugged if sending the bytes with another terminal than Proteus will work?

Comment: What does the Proteus oscilloscope show? Wouldn't it be a good idea to use a matching baud rate?